# Getting Value from clicked div's ID - php mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently beginning in php mysqli connections and such, and I'm working on a real estate website design prototype.

As of now I've managed to create a search form which displays every single house available for purchase listed in the mysql database.

Now my task is that when the user clicks one of the homes it activates another .php form which shows a more detailed page.

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to do this.

I'm guessing when the user clicks the div he wants, the php form should get a unique value from said div to query the database for that specific property but I'm at a loss here.

This is the Code for the listed available homes:

```
<?php
echo "<div id='parent'>";
echo "<section class='responsive HomeBox filterDiv' id='";
echo $resultados['tipo']."";
echo "'>";
echo "<div class='HomeBoxImg'>";
echo "<img class='img-thumbnail img-responsive' alt='Forest' 
src='img/propiedades/";
echo $resultados['nombre']."";
?>
/1.jpg' onerror="this.src='img/default.jpg'">
<?php
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='HomeBoxInfo'>";
echo "<h1>";
echo $resultados['direccion']."";
echo "<h2>";
echo $resultados['estructura']."";
echo "- ";
echo $resultados['tipo']."";
echo "</h2>";
echo "</h1>";
echo "<hr style='width:100%;'>";
echo "<div class='homeboxdetailboxes'>";
echo "<img src='img/icons/bed.png'' alt='Dormitorios'>";
echo "<h4>Dormitorios</h4>";
echo "<h5>";
echo $resultados['dormitorios']."";
echo "</h5>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='homeboxdetailboxes'>";
echo "<img src='img/icons/rooms.png'' alt='Ambientes'>";
echo "<h4>Ambientes</h4>";
echo "<h5>";
echo $resultados['ambientes']."";
echo "</h5>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='homeboxdetailboxes'>";
echo "<img src='img/icons/toilet.png'' alt='Baños'>";
echo "<h4>Baños</h4>";
echo "<h5>";
echo $resultados['baños']."";
echo "</h5>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='homeboxdetailboxes'>";
echo "<img src='img/icons/price.png'' alt='Precio'>";
echo "<h4>Precio</h4>";
echo "<h5>";
echo $resultados['precio']."";
echo "</h5>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</section>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

So what I'm missing would be the php form for displaying a whole new page based on an id or something provided by the user clicking on of these items.

Comment: Welcome, you should wrap each house or button into anchor tag such as `<a>Button</a>` now when you populate these houses on your first page. You can do following `<a href="details.php?id=x:">View Details</a>` now in your details.php page you will do `GET['id']` and grab data from the database that belongs to that house and populate it on the page. Let me know if that was clear enough?

Comment: Hey thanks for answering @IamCavic !, I'm still working on it so i did the <a> part, now whenever i click on any of the buttons i get this adress websitename.com/details.php?id=1: websitename.com/details.php?id=2: websitename.com/details.php?id=45: etc - is that okay or should it miss that : at the end ?

After that i'm also kind of confused on the GET['id'] part for the details.php file!, Sorry for bothering you, i'm sure it's a piece of cake for you :) Thanks for the help

Comment: No that is  great... So now on the details.php page your code will look something like this: `$houseID = $_GET["id"]` now your `$houseID` or what ever you like to name it will have the ID that you passed in the url such as `details.php?id=23` so your`$houseID = 23` now you can use that to do MySQL call and get any data that you need for showing it on details page. It is same as your main page

Comment: FYI, you should refrain form putting all your HTML in `echo` statements in your PHP.  Write your HTML (with indentation!) and when you need to print a variable value form PHP, put `<?php echo $variable; ?>`.  From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, says: *For outputting large blocks of text, dropping out of PHP parsing mode is generally more efficient than sending all of the text through echo or print.*.  Proper indentation is key for readability.

Comment: It's also easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript/JQuery here, like you can add following

```
echo '<div id="parent" class="number_<?php echo $resultados['nombre']; ?>">';
```

then to get specific elements id you can use:

```
var unique_id = document.getElementById('#parent').className.split('_')[1] //Javascript
var unique_id = $('#parent').attr('class').split('_')[1]; //Jquery
```

than you can use Ajax request or you can use javascript to change url of current page like:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.some_url/'+unique_id;
```

or you can even wrap each estate item inside , and inside this form put hidden input element like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="unique_number" value="<?php echo $resultados['nombre']; ?>">
```

and hook on click event on Javascript or JQuery to submit the form.